# How large was the kaioken Goku used against Lord Slug?

Tags: dragon-ball-movies

I've read in the internet there is some official guide which says the kaioken Goku used against Lord Slug was larger than kaioken x20. Does anyone know how large was the kaioken Goku used against Lord Slug?

[image]

Comment: quite sure Lord Slug predates Dragonball Super by a fair bit so i removed the tag, unless there's something in this that ties it to Dragonball Super besides it being Dragonball

Comment: sorry, it's the habit of adding the 2 tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the movie *Dragon Ball Z: Lord Slug*, after Piccolo transfers his energy to Goku, he goes *Kaioken times 100* and defeats Lord Slug.

A [clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tfmjDg3E5-4) indicating the same.